# Display the results of a SELECT COUNT(*) in PHP

Tags: php, sql, count

Current trying to display the results of a `SELECT COUNT(*)` from SQL within my website. I'm 100% new to PHP and SQL so understand this must be the basics! If anyone could recommend a good book or website to learn that would also be great.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
$sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_directory");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
?>

<?php echo $result ; ?>
```

The results are 28 and work if i run the following within the SQL box from phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_directory
```

Appreciate anyone help or advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you did not execute the query using mysql_query() function.

you need to do like this

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

$sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_directory");
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
 //-----------^  need to run query here

 $result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
 //here you can echo the result of query
 echo $result[0];

?>

<?php echo $result[0]; ?>
```

Note: if you have started learning PHP/Mysql then  try to use mysqli_* functions. mysql_ will be deprecated in future PHP versions.

Comment: Hi Maz, I'm getting the following error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: please first check if you db connection is ok. mysql_connect is ok then mysql_select_db is correct. 3rd. print your query and run it directly in phpmyadmin and see there is not issue in query

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is an array, so you should use `$result[0]` or `$result[0][0]`

if you use `print_r($result)` you will see the structure of your array and which once you should use.

also you did not use `mysql_query($sql)`.
 you should use it like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$out = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print($out[0][0]); // or print($out[0]);
```

Comment: `$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` will cause the error because `mysql_fetch_array()` method needs resource argument, but the OP use `$sql` which is a string.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw thanx bro... I didn't notice it.

Comment: great! your answer seems right! i hope OP notices your changes and accepts as the right answer

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me.. geeez.. how hard can it be..HARD apparently

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM genericsignup WHERE REF LIKE '".$compref."'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql);
$out = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
print($out[0]);

Answer (score 1):

Hello , if you are fresher then you can read w3schools.com   enjoy

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM project_directory";
$result = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$my=$result['count'];
echo $my;
?>
```

Comment: again! `$result = mysql_num_rows($sql);` will cause the error because `mysql_num_rows()` method needs *resource* argument but `$sql` is just a string. incorrect answer!

Comment: I'm just confused, nothing has worked... I continue to get a number of errors. I assumed this would be easy? It's seems to be a lot harder than expected.

Comment: it is very easy, @tgcowell, please check **Amir Noori** and **Agha Umair Ahmed**'s answers again. their answers are corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
$abc="SELECT count(*) as c FROM output WHERE question1=4";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$abc);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['c'];
    }       
}
```

ITS works completely

Answer (score 1):

```
$qry_appr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE admin_panel_id ='$id' AND status = 'ON'";
$qry_data = mysqli_query($con, $qry_appr);
$approve_count = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_data);
$toatalCount = array_shift($approve_count);
echo $toatalCount;
```

This will also fine but this is do what returning 0 index value by shifting fetch array.this can use without alias. welcome all

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Get the result from the resource returned by the count query:

```
      $resource = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(col) FROM table");
      $count = mysql_result($resource,0);
```

Or, get the number of rows from the resource returned by the query (without count).

```
      $resource = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM table WHERE col IS NOT NULL");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($resource);
```

I would recommend that you use the first, the reason being is that it is unnecessary to extract all the data from the table when you only need the count.

Comment: `$rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);` will cause the error because `mysql_num_rows()` method needs *resource* as a argument and `$sql` is a string

Comment: I've tried the above code... and now i'm getting the following error Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: <?php
                        $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_directory");
                        $rows = mysql_num_rows($sql)
                        echo $rows ;
                        ?>

Answer (score 0):

if you are new in php and mysql try to use mysqli not mysql

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_directory";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $result ;
?>
```

Comment: `$result = mysql_num_rows($sql);` will cause the error ... because the method `mysql_num_rows()` needs *resource* argument but `$sql` is simply a string.

Comment: you need to execute query first $query = mysql_query($sql); and then $result = mysql_num_rows($query); sorry not written execute query